# Collada loader not working properly

Tags: three.js, blender, collada

I created a model in blender, rigged it and created some simple animation, after which i exported to .dae. The animation looks fine when i open the .dae file, however after i loaded it into browser using three.js, the animation is not working.

The model is still loaded, but it looks like the one in blender edit mode. (with arm stretched out and standing straight), and there is no animation at all even though there is no error in console port.

```
new THREE.ColladaLoader().load('../models/myworkblend3.dae', 
    function(collada) {
        monster = collada.scene;
        monster.scale.set(100, 100, 100);
        monster.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
        monster.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;

        skin = collada.skins[ 0 ];
        monster.updateMatrix();
        scene.add(monster);
        // enable shadows for an object
        monster.castShadow = true;
        monster.receiveShadow = true;
});
```

and the animation code is

```
function animate() {

requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    if ( t > 60 ) t = 0;
    if ( skin ) {

        for ( var i = 0; i < skin.morphTargetInfluences.length; i++ ) {     // length is 101
                skin.morphTargetInfluences[ i ] = 0;
        }
        // enable the keyframe one by one
        skin.morphTargetInfluences[ Math.floor( t ) ] = 1;
        t += 0.5;    //this prolongs the waiting time 
    }

render();

}
```

Any help would be sincerely appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ColladaLoader in three.js is experimental and is not maintained anymore. Anyway, this ColladaLoader is your best shot, unfortunately.

I recommend you post this bug on official GitHub three.js [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) 
Feel free to add functionality and fix problems like that.